# Linking all frameworks as optional

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, dynamic-linking

I read [this documentation article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160418012233/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html) about library and framework linking and the section below drew my attention:

> ... an Optional framework will be loaded only if needed. The initial load of the application will be faster if a large library that is never needed is designated as Optional.

So I'm asking why wouldn't I set all frameworks as `Optional`, if they will load when necessary? What would be the drawback?

Answer (score 1):

Using optional libraries requires additional code as it makes use of [weak linking](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html):

```
if (MyWeakLinkedFunction != NULL)
{
    result = MyWeakLinkedFunction();
}
```

That makes using the library something of a pain; I would rather *know* that the symbols are available when the program loads, and if they are not the O/S can deal with telling the user.

Comment: What about frameworks? Or more so, Apple frameworks like `Accounts`, `AVFoundation`?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Your answer talked about libraries, not frameworks. Isn't the `will be loaded only if needed` from the documentation replacing your `if (MyWeakLinkedFunction != NULL)`? Why are you saying that you need to check, if it says that it will be loaded if needed? `needed`, from my point of view, being the `result = MyWeakLinkedFunction();`.

Comment: Frameworks are just dressed-up dynamic libraries.  The danger of just assuming the optional symbol is available is that you can simply crash by dereferencing `NULL`.  If the library contained an Objective-C class you would also need to use similar techniques to ensure they are available.  If you *know* the symbol is available then there is no harm, however there is no advantage either.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks. So, the `will be loaded only if needed ` will happen on this line: `result = MyWeakLinkedFunction();`?

Comment: Yes; however that's true of required libraries too, assuming that symbol was the first one accessed from the library.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing because of this line

> The initial load of the application...

You might have a "large" load, later in the application if you do set as optionaly, where it might be unwanted. So loading the framework early, will decrease load time later.

That is what I imagine anyway

Comment: But at the same time, a big app load time is unwanted, and this is one of my problems too. And I thought that I can decrease the load time if I mark them as `Optional`.

Comment: Well, you could just mark the ones that is less likely to be used as Optional. And the ones that will be used everytime, all the time should not be optional. But otherwise, test it out, and see if it is a problem, when everything is optional :)