# iOS System Library can import even not add to "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm facing some curious situation on Xcode 11.5, 11.6.
My Project was seems to not need import "SafariServices.framework",  and I removed that.

But project still can "import SafariServices"...
How could happen this ??

I suspected...
・Some builds exists?? -> No. Cleaning project not worked.
・Some another Libraries which in Carthage or Cocoapods has that? -> No. I've searched "Safari, SafariServices" in project directory, and no founded.

I hope someone gives me how to deep dive knowing Xcode Library structures... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- All the frameworks `UIKit, AVFoundation, CoreGraphic...` already in the system I believe.
- As you can see, all of those frameworks (including SafariServices) belonging to the iOS system.

[image]

- So basically, you don't have to add those frameworks into your project settings. Just import in code.
- **BUT** if you care about the Require/Optional frameworks, you can check this out: [Optional & Require frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421099/linking-all-frameworks-as-optional)